# How can I get the timestamp of each command line in my terminal history?

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, timestamp

I would like to know how long a command that I entered into my terminal has been running. It would be great to be able to get the timestamp of every command in my history. Let me know if you need any more information in order to be able to answer this question. Thanks.

EDIT: I am using a bash terminal.

Comment: Do you actually mean the _timestamp_ or the _duration_ ("how long a command [...] has been running") of each command? That's not quite clear from your question.

Comment: For this particular case, all I really need is the duration, which I could get if I knew the timestamp of the command. Really, it would be cool to know how to get both the duration and the timestamp. Thanks.

Comment: That can be done with `time <command>`, as Hitman47 mentioned in his [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493145/#comment20198586_14493177), but its output won't land in your history. You could probably also play around with [PROMPT_COMMAND](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming you are using command prompt

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

then

```
history
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-history-display-date-time/

Comment: Thanks, though it seems that this won't get the timestamps of commands that were executed before HISTTIMEFORMAT was set.

Comment: @abw333 actually i just tried and it did show the timestamps even before the HISTTIMEFORMAT was set. for how to get the duration, i think you can use "time <your command>" but I can't think of how to combine the result of history and the time command

Answer (score 11):

`history -f` is a good way to prints timestamp.

Comment: Possibly this is not "universal" but rather specific to the "z" shell: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63552102/2153622

Answer (score 4):

I don't think I know how to show the duration, but you can view the time you ran the command by setting the HISTTIMEFORMAT variable.

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
```

Then call your "history"

```
history
```

If you only want to see last 10 commands

```
history | tail
```

Hope this help :)